# Expect a value within a given range using Google Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I want to specify an expectation that a value is between an upper and lower bound, inclusively.

Google Test provides LT,LE,GT,GE, but no way of testing a range that I can see. You could use `EXPECT_NEAR` and juggle the operands, but in many cases this isn't as clear as explicitly setting upper and lower bounds.

Usage should resemble:

```
EXPECT_WITHIN_INCLUSIVE(1, 3, 2); // 2 is in range [1,3]
```

How would one add this expectation?

Answer (score 24):

Google mock has richer composable matchers than google test alone:

```cpp
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using namespace ::testing;

// expect that x is >= 1 and <= 3
EXPECT_THAT(x, AllOf(Ge(1),Le(3)));
```

Maybe that would work for you.

See the [googletest `matchers.md` document under the "Composite Matchers" section, here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#composite-matchers)

Gabriel, I generally try to avoid introducing macros because they don't compose well and you end up with a proliferation of them. We should only really need ASSERT_THAT and EXPECT_THAT once we're using Matchers.

But that's not to say I don't value a built-in range check. I just wouldn't do it with macros. I would do it with a higher-level matcher. So:

--- UPDATE ---

For notational convenience, a function returning such a composite matcher can be easily written:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto IsInRange(T lo, T hi) {
    return AllOf(Ge((lo)), Le((hi))));
}

EXPECT_THAT(value, IsInRange(min, max));
ASSERT_THAT(value, IsInRange(min, max));
```

Comment: I really like your answer. I wrapped it with a macro [in my answer I just added here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75786774/4561887) to make it even simpler to use like this: `EXPECT_RANGE(value, min, max);` and `ASSERT_RANGE(value, min, max);`

Answer (score 24):

Using just Google Test (not mock), then the simple, obvious answer is:

```
EXPECT_TRUE((a >= 1) && (a <= 3)); // a is between 1 and 3 inclusive
```

I find this more readable than some of the Mock based answers.

--- begin edit --

The simple answer above not providing any useful diagnostics

You can use `AssertionResult` to define a custom assert that does produce useful a useful error message like this.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

::testing::AssertionResult IsBetweenInclusive(int val, int a, int b)
{
    if((val >= a) && (val <= b))
        return ::testing::AssertionSuccess();
    else
        return ::testing::AssertionFailure()
               << val << " is outside the range " << a << " to " << b;
}

TEST(testing, TestPass)
{
    auto a = 2;
    EXPECT_TRUE(IsBetweenInclusive(a, 1, 3));
}

TEST(testing, TestFail)
{
    auto a = 5;
    EXPECT_TRUE(IsBetweenInclusive(a, 1, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would define these macros:

```
#define EXPECT_IN_RANGE(VAL, MIN, MAX) \
    EXPECT_GE((VAL), (MIN));           \
    EXPECT_LE((VAL), (MAX))

#define ASSERT_IN_RANGE(VAL, MIN, MAX) \
    ASSERT_GE((VAL), (MIN));           \
    ASSERT_LE((VAL), (MAX))
```

Comment: Simple and efficient... until "<<" operator is used after the macro: it will only apply to the second (*_LE) googletest macro.

Comment: I like your work and mentioned it [in my new answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75786774/4561887) The answer I added _does_ work well with the `<<` operator to add additional error messages to print.

Answer (score 6):

There is a nice example in [google mock cheat sheet](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#defining-matchers):

```
using namespace testing;
MATCHER_P2(IsBetween, a, b,
           std::string(negation ? "isn't" : "is") + " between " + PrintToString(a)
           + " and " + PrintToString(b))
{
    return a <= arg && arg <= b;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
TEST(MyTest, Name) {
    EXPECT_THAT(42, IsBetween(40, 46));
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I created a macro to do this that resembles other macros in the Google Test lib.

```
#define EXPECT_WITHIN_INCLUSIVE(lower, upper, val) \
  do { \
    EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2(::testing::internal::CmpHelperGE, val, lower); \
    EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2(::testing::internal::CmpHelperLE, val, upper); \
  } while (0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this introduces a reliance on ::internal:: names that can change without notice. This isn't supported.

Comment: Why not base it on the public macros, and avoid the aforementioned issue: `EXPECT_GE(val, lower); EXPECT_LE(val, upper);`

Answer (score 1):

[Using an Existing Boolean Function](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#using-an-existing-boolean-function) in Google Test which don't need google mock.The link is quite specific.

Here is the example.

> ```
> // Returns true iff m and n have no common divisors except 1.
> bool MutuallyPrime(int m, int n) { ... }
> const int a = 3;
> const int b = 4;
> const int c = 10;
> ```
>
> the assertion EXPECT_PRED2(MutuallyPrime, a, b); will succeed, while
>   the assertion EXPECT_PRED2(MutuallyPrime, b, c); will fail with the
>   message
>
> ```
> !MutuallyPrime(b, c) is false, where
>
> b is 4
>
> c is 10
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers here, I really think the most-beautiful and perfect answer is a blend between [@Billy Donahue's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21972516/4561887) and [@Alexander Voitenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61968208/4561887).

So, here's what I recommend. I think this should become part of the official googletest/googlemock code base:

### Quick summary

```cpp
// 1. definitions
#define EXPECT_RANGE(val, min, max) EXPECT_THAT((val), \
    ::testing::AllOf(::testing::Ge((min)), ::testing::Le((max))))
#define ASSERT_RANGE(val, min, max) ASSERT_THAT((val), \
    ::testing::AllOf(::testing::Ge((min)), ::testing::Le((max))))

// 2. usage
EXPECT_RANGE(value, min, max);
ASSERT_RANGE(value, min, max);
```

### Details

Here is a more-complete picture:

```cpp
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

/// Expect or assert that value `val` is within the range of `min` to `max`, 
/// inclusive. ie: `val` is tested to be >= `min` and <= `max`.
/// See:
/// 1. googletest `matchers.md` document under the "Composite Matchers" section, 
///    here:
///    https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#composite-matchers
/// 1. [My answer with this code] https://stackoverflow.com/a/75786774/4561887
#define EXPECT_RANGE(val, min, max) EXPECT_THAT((val), \
    ::testing::AllOf(::testing::Ge((min)), ::testing::Le((max))))
#define ASSERT_RANGE(val, min, max) ASSERT_THAT((val), \
    ::testing::AllOf(::testing::Ge((min)), ::testing::Le((max))))


TEST(Simulation, TrivialEndToEnd)
{
    // ...test setup stuff goes here...

    // Usage example: expect that the `distance_traveled_miles` value is within
    // the range 1151.77 to 1151.97, inclusive.
    EXPECT_RANGE(stats->distance_traveled_miles, 1151.77, 1151.97);
}
```

The error output if the test fails is really nice too. Here's what is printed in the event of a failure:

```text
src/main_unittest.cpp:194: Failure
Value of: (stats->distance_traveled_miles)
Expected: (is >= 1151.77) and (is <= 1151.97)
  Actual: 1151.6666666667204 (of type double)
[  FAILED  ] Simulation.TrivialEndToEnd (0 ms)
```

You can also add C++-style prints to the error message if desired, using the `<<` output print operator, like this:

```cpp
EXPECT_RANGE(stats->distance_traveled_miles, 1151.77, 1151.97) 
    << "Your custom failure message goes here.\n";
```

The line just above will produce this output in the event of a failure:

```text
src/main_unittest.cpp:194: Failure
Value of: (stats->distance_traveled_miles)
Expected: (is >= 1151.77) and (is <= 1151.97)
  Actual: 1151.6666666667204 (of type double)
Your custom failure message goes here.

[  FAILED  ] Simulation.TrivialEndToEnd (0 ms)
```

### References:

1. I first saw the `EXPECT_THAT(x, AllOf(Ge(1),Le(3)));` usage [in @Billy Donahue's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21972516/4561887).
2. https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md

   1. Learn about the `AllOf(m1, m2, ..., mn)` composite matcher [here under the section "Composite Matchers"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#composite-matchers)
   2. Learn about the `Ge()` ("greater than or equal to") and `Le()` ("less than or equal to") matchers [here under the section "Multi-argument Matchers"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#multi-argument-matchers-multiargmatchers)

Comment: Gabriel, I generally try to avoid introducing macros because they don't compose well and you end up with a proliferation of them. We should only really need ASSERT_THAT and EXPECT_THAT once we're using Matchers.

But that's not to say I don't value a built-in range check. I just wouldn't do it with macros. I would do it with a higher-level matcher. So:

namespace t = ::testing;

template <typename T>
auto IsInRange(T lo, T hi) {
    return t::AllOf(t::Ge((lo)), t::Le((hi))));
}

EXPECT_THAT(value, IsInRange(min, max));
ASSERT_THAT(value, IsInRange(min, max));

Comment: I do not think that would be a good addition to the GTest, because something like `EXPECT_LE( val1, val2, val3, val4 )` which tests`val1 <= val2 <= val3 <= val4` (in a mathematical sense) is much more versatile.

Comment: @tommsch, then I hope you make that, and see if you can get it merged. But, currently they have none of it.